# How to call global function from class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class, oop

I have the following code:

```
def __static_func(name):
    print 'Name = ' + name

class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def fun(self):
        __static_func(self.name)

a = A('foo')
a.fun()
```

When launched on Python 2.7, it produces

```
NameError: global name '_A__static_func' is not defined
```

So the question is how do I call global function from within class method?

Comment: The fact that this still happens in python 3.7 is actually hilarious. What the heck, python.

Comment: Just don't use a function name starting with double underscore.

Comment: @Bazingaa Why is the best answer so far posted as a comment?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Ok, I have noticed that people don't appreciate only texts as answers. But I can post it since you mentioned

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was recently reading a book "[Learning Python by O'Reilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do)" (Page 944, Chapter 31) and it was mentioned that when you use double underscores `__` as the starting characters of a method or a variable in the `Class`, it automatically appends the `_classname` to that function where `classname` is the class name. This is done to localize a name to the class to which it belongs. This is called **Name Mangling** in the context of **Pseudoprivate class attributes**.

This way you can use the same name `__variable` in two different classes `A` and `B` as the variables/methods will become privately `_A__variable` and `_B__variable` respectively. So just name your global function something else with a single underscore for example to avoid this conflict.

Comment: But why does python do this? The method is clearly not defined in the class, so why does it get mangled as though it were? I had a hard time finding this answer when searching for a solution to this problem, especially when trying to learn Python coming from Java and C#

Answer (score 5):

Don't use double underscores.

```
def _static_func(name):
    print 'Name = ' + name

class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def fun(self):
        _static_func(self.name)

a = A('foo')
a.fun()
```

Should work

Comment: No, double underscores are not "for predefined stuff". This is only valid if you're talking about leading **and** trailing double underscores.