# How to generate runtime class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to generate a group of classes with same methods but different `name` attribute. Eg,

```py
class A:
    name = '1'
    def f(self):
        print('call')

class B
    name = '2'
    def f(self):
        print('call')

class C
    name = '3'
    def f(self):
        print('call')

server.register_handler_class(A)
server.register_handler_class(B)
server.register_handler_class(C)
```

Values of `name` are loaded from `xx.conf` file.
How to do this? Do I need `metaclass` or `__new__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need `type` and `globals`:

```
new_class_names = ['A', 'B', 'C']

def new_class_init(self):
    print(f'{self} was called.')

for class_name in new_class_names:
    globals()[class_name] = type(class_name, (), {'__init__': new_class_init}
```

`type` can be [called with three parameters](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#type): `name`, `bases` and `dict` to return a new class.

`name` is the name of the new class, `bases` a `tuple` containing all its base classes and `dict` a `dict` with key-value pairs representing the method names and actual functions to be bound as methods that the new class should have.

Then, of course, to add them programmatically to the global namespace, we can reference the global `dict` by calling `globals`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, if you pre-append your variable names by `__`, while executing them, the name of the class is automatically appended to the beginning of the respective variables of the classes. So while accessing the variables via Class instance, the variables will become `_A__name`, `_B__name` and `_C__name`. This allows you to use same names without running into problems with conflicting names. You can read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52853615/how-to-call-global-function-from-class-method/52853949#52853949). I am not sure if this is what you meant.

The same can be done for methods as well: `__f`

Hence you can use

```
class A:
    __name = '1'
    def f(self):
        print('call')

class B
    __name = '2'
    def f(self):
        print('call')

class C
    __name = '3'
    def f(self):
        print('call')
```

Comment: No, `name` is used by 3rd party `server.register_handler_class()`. I cannot change it. Anyway, thank you for the trick.